# Better way to write a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, view

I'm creating a view after joining a table and a view.
The view contains some actual columns in the join and some of them are calculated columns(lets call them type1). Some of them are calculations of the calculated columns (type2).
Is there any way  I can reference type1 columns to calculate type2 just by their names instead of writing the entire code again? ( I don't want to create another subquery either), just checking if there is any efficient way to write the code. Not posting actual code here ,this is short form of what I'm trying to do:

```
    Create view ABCD 
     col1,col2 , calc_col1, calc_col2 , Calc_col3
   as 
     select a.col1 as col1 ,
            a.col2 as col2,
            case when  some_calulations then 2 else 0  end as calc_col1,
           ( case when  some_calulations then 2 else 0  end) - a.somecol as calc_col2 ,
      ( ( case when  some_calulations then 2 else 0  end) - a.somecol ) + 5 )as calc_col3 
 from Table1 as a
   left join view2 as b
   on join_condition
```

Comment: You could write it as a function passing in the needed values for "Some values" but that seems like it would be inefficient execution, though easier maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`lateral subqueries`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)

```
select
    a.col1 as col1,
    a.col2 as col2,
    c.calc_col1,
    d.calc_col2,
    d.calc_col2 + 5 as calc_col3 
from
    Table1 a
    left join
    view2 b on join_condition
    cross join lateral
    (select case when some_calulations then 2 else 0 end as calc_col1) c
    cross join lateral
    (select calc_col1 - a.somecol as calc_col2) d
```

Answer (score 1):

**NO**, you can't. Either you use the entire expression again (or) use a subquery and in your outer query reference the column name